# Validator giving stray start tag error but I have no script and nothing outside <html> except !DOCTYPE

Tags: html, validation

I'm getting the "Error: Stray start tag `script`" in the W3 Nu Html Checker. I have no script (because I haven't learned any yet, lol) and I also have nothing outside my `<html>` tags except for `!DOCTYPE`.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://res.cloudinary.com/amanda-sterling-art/image/upload/v1578777557/AmandaSterling.Art/favicon_dkiz5j.ico" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Walter+Turncoat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <title>Amanda Sterling Art</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div id="title-box">
        <h1>Amanda Sterling Art</h1>
        </div>
        <div id='link-box'>

<div id="tiles">

    <div class="tile"><a href="https://www.etsy.com/shop/AmandaSterlingArt"><img class="preview" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/amanda-sterling-art/image/upload/v1581724527/AmandaSterling.Art/IMG_2826_zlbtfj.jpg" alt="Etsy Thumbnail"></a><p class="preview-caption">Etsy</p></div>

    <div class="tile"><a href="https://www.redbubble.com/people/uhhhhmanda-art"><img class="preview" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/amanda-sterling-art/image/upload/v1581720260/AmandaSterling.Art/work-43950676-primary_square-u-cotton-tote_hlqyjp_duibu3.jpg" alt="Redbubble Thumbnail"></a><p class="preview-caption">Redbubble</p></div>

              <div class="tile"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/amandasterling_art/"><img class="preview" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/amanda-sterling-art/image/upload/v1581720281/AmandaSterling.Art/Day_26_-_fotor_qlica5_trfclz.jpg" alt="Art Instagram Thumbnail"></a><p class="preview-caption">Instagram (art)</p></div>

      <div class="tile"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/sterlingfink/"><img class="preview" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/amanda-sterling-art/image/upload/v1581722432/AmandaSterling.Art/56276160_313103576022109_2788164958563511652_n.jpg_ylizzi.jpg" alt="Photography Instagram Thumbnail"></a><p class="preview-caption">Instagram (photography)</p></div>

      <div class="tile"><a href="https://twitter.com/SterlingFink"><img class="preview" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/amanda-sterling-art/image/upload/v1581723362/AmandaSterling.Art/twitter_kibija.png" alt="Twitter Thumbnail"></a><p class="preview-caption">Twitter</p></div>

        <div class="tile"><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/uhhhhmanda/"><img class="preview" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/amanda-sterling-art/image/upload/v1581724021/AmandaSterling.Art/pinterest_ep4uha.png" alt="Pinterest Thumbnail"></a><p class="preview-caption">Pinterest</p></div>

        <div class="tile"><a href="mailto:amandasterlingart@gmail.com"><img class="preview" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/amanda-sterling-art/image/upload/v1581725266/AmandaSterling.Art/IMG_0310_Fotor_half_e79jn7.jpg" alt="Contact Thumbnail"></a><p class="preview-caption">Contact</p></div>
    <!-- end of tiles -->
    </div> <!--end of link box-->
</div>
            <footer><small>&copy; Amanda Sterling Fink 2020</small></footer>
    </div> <!-- flex-container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know why ```!DOCTYPE``` isn't showing up in my pasted code, but I promise it's there.

Comment: [This](https://alt.html.narkive.com/2zkSQZwI/error-stray-start-tag-script) might help. Do a "show source" before checking the page for script tags.

Comment: Fixed your `!DOCTYPE` issue view my edit to notice the new lines and where the language specifier is.

Comment: Since the code you posted doesn't generate the error you claim, there must be some other code somewhere that is missing from this question.

Comment: @RobMoll How interesting! There's a bunch of garbledegook there that isn't in my original code! Must be my host. *sigh* Thank you!

Comment: @MartinBarker Thank you! I see how you did that and I'll make a note for next time.

Comment: @j08691 I should have specified that when running the validator I wasn't pasting in my html as I did in my question, I was using Check By Address and inputting my URL. When I do that, as I learned from Rob just now, there is additional code added in by my host company after my ```</html>```.

Answer (score 0):

When your checking source codes for errors you should always check that there is not stuff being prepended or appended to your file. if there is change hosting providers there are loads that offer free hosting without in-page advertisements use one of them. [https://www.free-webhosts.com/](http://www.free-webhosts.com/search-webhosts.php?SA=&CO=1) (you want one without forced adds)

You should also always go to the page in the browser and view the source of the page from the server, not the code you have written to check for appended or prepended content to do this go to the page in your browser and (right-click, view source)

Comment: I'm limited in my options for hosting because I have a .art URL (seemed like a great idea at the time ...) but at least the company I'm using doesn't put ads on my site. I'm not sure what the appended code does because I just started learning JS yesterday (literally!). I did check my code from the page rather than my saved file, but I did this out of laziness. Now I know it's a good idea and to enable "view source"!

Comment: @Uhhhhmanda I would be more careful if it's not adverts it's tracking systems and with GDPR you need to know what tracking systems because you need to warn people about it you also don't have the option to tell the host not to put it on there also contrary to GDPR.